# Marionette ItemView events - bind multiple functions to single event

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js, marionette

Is it possible to bind multiple functions to single event in a Marionette ItemView
eg.

```
events: { 
"click #div1": "func1 func2" 
}
```

This doesn't work at all in ItemView. However, its supposed to work fine in CollectionView: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/355.

I also tried

```
events: { 
"click #div1": "func1",
"click #div1": "func2" 
}
```

But this results in a call only to func2!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `events` is an object, and Backbone [iterates over its keys](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/c71336641ee0354776556cdcfa5522f23ca14abf/backbone.js#L1306) and since you can't have duplicate keys you can't declare two handlers on the same event.

You can instead use a single event-handler that again calls the functions you want to invoke.

```
events: {
    'click #div1': 'onDiv1Click'
},

onDiv1Click: function() {
    this.func1();
    this.func2();
}
```